# ArcMap continuous scrolling when Shift key pressed?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.4

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1.

I need to use the shift key to select multiple segments to merge them together, this has been working fine until today when I press the shift key and the map immediately starts scrolling. The only way I have managed to get it to stop it by pressing it multiple times.

However, when I go to use it again to select multiple features it starts scrolling again.

Can anyone help?

I'm fairly new to the program.

Comment: Do you mean you're "roaming" (the map view follows pans according to your cursor)? Usually the key for that is 'q'. I'd check your keyboard settings to make sure it's still using the language you think it is.